# Skip validation for some members in Devise model during password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

My User (Devise) model also has name, city, nation, phone members.

In the create registration page - I `validates_presence_of city, nation, phone, name, email, :on => :create`

In the edit registration page - I `validates_presence_of city, nation, phone, name, :on => :update`

Now when I set a new password on forgot_password_page, it asks for the presence of city, nation, phone, name inside `Devise::PasswordsController#update`

How can I handle selective validations?

I am guessing it should be something like,

```
validates_presence_of city, nation, phone, name, :on => :update, :if => :not_recovering_password

def not_recovering_password
  # what goes here
end
```

Comment: you might be looking for this - http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/05/two-step-signup-with-devise/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from José - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1623

Comment: That's not even an answer! "My suggestion is to simply remove those validations."

Comment: Well, removing your project _does_ tend to remove your issues. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem because when my User is created not all its fields are required. The other fields' presence is checked `on: :update` using a validation.

So this is how I solved:

```
validates :birthdate, presence: true, on: :update, unless: Proc.new{|u| u.encrypted_password_changed? }
```

The method `encrypted_password_changed?` is the one used in the [Devise Recoverable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L31).

Comment: May I know how this works? What does `encrypted_password_changed?` hold?

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm! :)

Comment: You can just say `unless: :encrypted_password_changed?`

Comment: Pietro @mmike I'm afraid this only solve the issue of the question. Yet, you should be aware that this solution will also skip the validation in User edit profile form.

Comment: @prajwaldp this will skip the validation when user reset password, and also when user updating their password in User edit profile form. Please refer to this [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) for **column_changed?**.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question looking for an answer to a similar question, so hopefully someone else finds this useful.  In my case, I was dealing with legacy data that had missing information for fields that were previously not required but were later made required.  Here's what I did, essentially, to finish the above code:

```
validates_presence_of city, nation, phone, name, :on => :update, :if => :not_recovering_password

def not_recovering_password
  password_confirmation.nil?
end
```

Basically, it uses the absence/presence of the password_confirmation field to know if a user is trying to change/reset their password.  If it's not filled, they are not changing it (and, thus, run your validations).  If it is filled, then they are changing/resetting, and, thus, you want to skip your validations.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, it should be the marked one, you saved my time thank you :)

Comment: You can just say `if: "password_confirmation.nil?"`

Answer (score 2):

In the Devise model you can override `reset_password!` and use your own validations. For example:

```
def reset_password!(new_password, new_password_confirmation)
  self.password = new_password
  self.password_confirmation = new_password_confirmation

  validates_presence_of     :password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of       :password, within: Devise.password_length, allow_blank: true

  if errors.empty?
    clear_reset_password_token
    after_password_reset
    save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

All provided answers here have the same problem: They will prevent the `User`'s validations from running **BOTH** when only updating the password **AND** when updating the entire `User` (from the /user/edit form).

What you really want: Prevent the `User`'s "other" validations from running **ONLY** when updating the password separately from all other attributes (via the token the `User` receives via the email).

So the correct solution is:

- Define a virtual attribute for `User`
- Override the Devise method [reset_password_by_token](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L134) to assign this virtual attribute the value `true`, for which you will
  check in the conditional validation.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Define a virtual attribute
  attribute :validate_as_passwordupdate, :boolean

  # Your conditional validations (check for the value of the virtual attribute)
  with_options if: Proc.new { |user| user.validate_as_passwordupdate != true } do
    validates :name,   presence: true
    validates :city,   presence: true
    validates :nation, presence: true
    validates :phone,  presence: true
  end

  # Override the original Devise method that is used for updating the
  #  password separately from all other attributes (via token received by email):
  #  Set the value of the virtual attribute
  def self.reset_password_by_token(attributes = {})
    original_token       = attributes[:reset_password_token]
    reset_password_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, original_token)

    recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:reset_password_token, reset_password_token)

    if recoverable.persisted?
      if recoverable.reset_password_period_valid?

        # ADD THIS LINE TO THE ORIGINAL CODE:
        # 
        recoverable.validate_as_passwordupdate = true

        recoverable.reset_password(attributes[:password], attributes[:password_confirmation])
      else
        recoverable.errors.add(:reset_password_token, :expired)
      end
    end

    recoverable.reset_password_token = original_token if recoverable.reset_password_token.present?
    recoverable
  end
  
end
```