# Rails Validation Triggers on resetting password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise

Here is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
has_many :events
has_many :appointments

validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, format: {with: /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/, message: 'solo se permiten letras y/o numeros' }, if: 'name.present?'
validates :lastname, format: {with: /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/, message: 'solo se permiten letras y/o numeros' }, if: 'lastname.present?'
validates :lastname, :presence => true

validates :document, :presence => true
validates_numericality_of :document, :on => :create, :message => "no es un numero", if: 'document.present?'

validates :cellphone, :presence => true
validates :cellphone, numericality:{ only_integer: true, message:"no es un numero"}, if: 'cellphone.present?', :on => :create
validates :cellphone, numericality:{ only_integer: true, message:"no es un numero"}, if: 'cellphone.present?', :on => :update
validates :cellphone, format: { with: /\d{11}/, message: "mal formato, deben ser 11 digitos, incluyendo codigo de area" }, if: "cellphone.present?", :on => :create
validates :cellphone, format: { with: /\d{11}/, message: "mal formato, deben ser 11 digitos, incluyendo codigo de area" }, if: "cellphone.present?", :on => :update

validates :phone, :presence => true
validates :phone, numericality:{ only_integer: true, message:"no es un numero"}, if: "phone.present?", :on => :create
validates :phone, format: { with: /\d{11}/, message: "mal formato, deben ser 11 digitos, incluyendo codigo de area" }, if: "phone.present?", :on => :create

validates_format_of :email,:with => Devise::email_regexp, :allow_blank => true

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     def medic_with_spec
        "#{especialidad}, #{name} #{lastname}"          
     end

     def evento_sin 
        events.where(available: "1")
     end
```

end

as you can see the validation :cellphone has :on => create and :on => update, so my problem is that when i reset my password from an email link and press update with a new password it shows cellphone validations errors since it has :on => update. How can i make this dissappear?

I tried if: 'cellphone.nil?', it works fine because cellphone is obvioulsy blank (reset password only requires password and password confirmation) but when i go to edit account information it wont validate a none-nil value.

Im using devise.

I read this link [Validation errors are triggered when I'm trying to reset password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849427/validation-errors-are-triggered-when-im-trying-to-reset-password) , its the exact same problem, but i have no idea how to implement what they said.

Im new on ruby on rails, if some1 can help me with this i have no idea how to implements advance ruby.

Comment: (One of my gripes about Rails.) Personally, I use separate form objects for stuff like this, at least when it's simple. In the past I've used context-sensitive validation, but it's easier to just create tiny DTOs, and it further separates the view from the domain objects. YMMV.

Comment: No clue of this, sorry

Answer (score 0):

you should disable validation if **password_confirmation** field is not nil (that means that password was changed). Here's a linked topic [Skip validation for some members in Devise model during password reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153251/skip-validation-for-some-members-in-devise-model-during-password-reset)

So, in your case that would be:

```
validates :cellphone, numericality:{ only_integer: true, message:"no es un numero"}, :if => :not_recovering_password, :on => :update

def not_recovering_password
  password_confirmation.nil?
end
```