# Validations running on devise password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

how can I stop validations running when entrant (user) updates password. Users cannot update their password.

```
    class Entrant < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :create
   validates :last_name, presence: true, on: :create

   validates :title, presence: true, on: :update
```

Attempted the steps described here -

[How To: Allow users to edit their password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)

But not sure if this is necessary as I'm trying to do only standard behaviour.

**Routes -**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



  get 'messages/judge_logout/' => "messages#judge_logout", :as => 'messages_judge_logout'
  get 'exporter/entrant'
  get 'exporter/entries'
  get 'exporter/results'
  get 'exporter/registered_not_entered'
  #get 'judge/index'
  #get 'judge/show'
  resources :judge, :only =>[:show,:index]

  get 'all_entries/list', as: 'all_entries_list'
  get 'all_entries/final_scores', as: 'all_scores_list'
  get '/all_entries/list', as: :admin_root
  resources :entries

  devise_for :entrants, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_for :judges, :controllers =>  { sessions: 'judges/sessions' }
  devise_for :admins

  resources :charges
  resources :votes, :only =>[:create,:update]
```

**Controller -**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:entrant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:entrant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :title, :address, :postcode, :main_phone_number, :secondary_phone_number, :website, :dob, :place_of_birth, :place_of_education, :degree_attained, :how_did_you_hear_about_newlight, :terms_of_service)
  end


  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    #edit_entrant_registration_path(resource)
    entries_path
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_entrant_registration_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    entries_path
  end

end
```

Comment: Try `validates :password, presence: true, on: :create`

Comment: Can you post your controller and relevant routes?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question. Seriously stuck with this, I've inherited the app.

Comment: I can't even run reset_password in console.. is recoverable even loaded? - `NoMethodError: undefined method 'reset_password' for #<Entrant:0x007f45470ac2b8>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip validation for some members in Devise model during password reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153251/skip-validation-for-some-members-in-devise-model-during-password-reset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is only because the validations are running on update, which means when the model password is changed the validations are running. Adding an `unless` conditional stopped the validation running.

[Answer to problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153251/skip-validation-for-some-members-in-devise-model-during-password-reset)